# Java min() method Not Returning Minimum Value in Array

Tags: java, arrays

I know that there's other strategies that I can use (e.g. sorting the array and then just returning the array's index at [0]), but I am just practicing other techniques to find the min value in an array.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayUtils {

    static int[] integers = new int[] {1, 3, 2, 10, 15, 30};

    public static int max(int[] integers) {
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
            if (integers[i] > i)
                max = integers[i];
        }
        return max;
    }

    public static int min(int[] integers) {
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
            if (integers[i] < i) {
                min = integers[i];
            }
        }
        return min;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(integers));
        System.out.println("Max value: " + max(integers));
        System.out.println("Min value: " + min(integers));
    }
}
```

---

Output:

```
[1, 3, 2, 10, 15, 30]
Max value: 30
Min value: 2147483647
```

Why does my logic work for the `max(int[] integers)` method but not my `min(int[] integers)` method?

Comment: `if (integers[i] < i) {` should probably be `if (integers[i] < min) {` - same for your max method

Comment: [Four years ago, in another universe...](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/162656/getting-max-and-min-values-from-array)

Answer (score 1):

Both of your functions are incorrect as you are comparing `integers[i]` to `i`. You need to compare to `min` or `max`. For `min()` try the following:

```
public static int min(int[] integers) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
        if (integers[i] < min) {  // <-- change here
            min = integers[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

You also need to make a similar change to `max()`. It was simply luck that it was producing a correct result with your `integers`.

Answer (score 1):

In both `min(...)` and `max(...)`, you compare `integers[i]` against `i` in the `if`-clause. You most probably intended to compare them against `min` and `max` respectively.

---

A remark on the comment you made: "*I know that there's other strategies that I can use (e.g. sorting the array and then just returning the array's index at [0])...*" - This solution is slower (time complexity of `O(n log n)` vs `O(n)`).

Comment: Isn't the time complexity determined by the type of sorting algorithm?

Comment: Sorting is one of the few problems for which a lower bound wrt. time complexity is known. Sorting based on key comparison has a lower bound of `O(n log n)`. There are tricks around this iff. a-priori knowledge of the domain is known. Radix- and bucket-sort utilize such a-priori knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing the values in the array to their *index*, not to the current minimum/maximum. Update your `min` function to include the follwoing statement in the `for` loop:

```
if (integers[i] < min) {
    min = integers[i];
}
```

You will want to do likewise with `max`.